# Unable to clearInterval();

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm working with a `setInterval`, that I cant seem to clear. I'm wholly unsure of why this might be:

```
function Slider(element) {

  this.i = 0;

  this.element = element;

  var self = this;

  this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log(self.timer);
    switch (self.i) {
      case 0:
        element.velocity({
          translateX: "-33.333333%"
        }, {
          duration: 750,
          delay: 4000
        }, "easeOut");
        $('.multi-nav .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.multi-nav .0').addClass("active");
        self.i++;
        break;
      case 1:
        element.velocity({
          translateX: "-66.666666%"
        }, {
          duration: 750,
          delay: 4000
        }, "easeOut");
        $('.multi-nav .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.multi-nav .1').addClass("active");
        self.i++;
        break;
      case 2:
        element.velocity({
          translateX: "0%"
        }, {
          duration: 750,
          delay: 4000
        }, "easeInQuart");
        $('.multi-nav .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.multi-nav .2').addClass("active");
        self.i = 0;
        break;
    }
  }, 5000);
}

Slider.prototype.stop = function() {
  window.clearInterval(this.timer);
  console.log(this.timer);
}

var id = 0;
var name = "slider_";
$(".multi").each(function() {
  uniqueName = name + id;
  window[uniqueName] = new Slider($(this));
  id++;
});


$(".multi-nav a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Stopping the object running on this object.
  var id = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(" ").pop();
  uniqueName = name + id;
  window[uniqueName].stop();
});
```

The parent element of the element thats being clicked on, contains the relevant number as a class. Which Im grabbing and attaching to the name in order to properly get the object.

MY issue seems to be with how I'm trying to stop it. Even if I go to the browser, and utilize the proper name for the object, and try and `.stop();` it, nothing happens. If I use the object name and `.timer` it, I get back a random number.

Any idea how I can get my intervals to properly clear?

---

**UPDATE**

After a bit more experimentation, it appears as though if I manually stop both objects, they both stop. However if just one is stopped, the animation continues for both. Any idea why that would be the case?

---

I've played with alternative [html](/questions/tagged/html)where there's only one slider, and it works as expected. As soon as there are two or more however, all sliders must have the `.stop()` method run before any of them stop, and in this case, all of them do. Which is obviously not the intention.

---

**UPDATE 2**

It also appears that within the same [html](/questions/tagged/html)structure, if I trigger the click event on both matching sets, as defined within the `.each()` loop, the `setInterval` will end, for both. Why is it that it wont end for an individual object?

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem. in sandbox like jsfiddle.net, plnkr.co, jsbin.com, codepen etc

Comment: You should check the `uniqueName` variable when you call stop. Are you sure that is pulling up correctly?

Comment: After some more messing around with it, it does look like the name is correct, but Im wondering if theres a scoping issue with the objects themselves. I can clear the interval, if I do so directly below where its created, within the .each() loop. But if i try and clear it anywhere else, it doesn't work. How would I go about making sure that when I declare - window[uniqueName] = new Slider($(this)); - it's available to be controlled globally?

Comment: are you using browser dev tools console for debugging? Can see any object in window or dom there and log variables or objects to console

Comment: I am, and I can see the object, but I cant clear the interval.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the above code into an editor and opened it in a browser, then called window.slider_***.stop(), and it cleared the intervals. Can you set up a demo online?

Comment: I'm afraid we're not able to give an answer without seeing the html

Comment: This should contain all the relevant html - http://cl.ly/dM3M

Comment: So I just changed the stop call on the click function to being expressly written out, and now its working - http://cl.ly/dMWo - I obviously cant do that though. Whats going on that would be causing it to fail when pulled dynamically?

Comment: In your click handler you have `$(this).parent().attr("class")` which gets the class of the nav element, not the anchor, so you get `uniqueName == "slider_multi-nav"`, instead of slider_0, slider_1, etc.

Comment: That can't be it. I'm console.log'ing it right before its called, and its the appropriate label. slider_0 or slider_1

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the timer handler globally.

```js
var timer = null;

function Slider(element) {

  this.i = 0;

  this.element = element;

  var self = this;

  timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log(timer);
    switch (self.i) {
      case 0:
        element.velocity({
          translateX: "-33.333333%"
        }, {
          duration: 750,
          delay: 4000
        }, "easeOut");
        $('.multi-nav .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.multi-nav .0').addClass("active");
        self.i++;
        break;
      case 1:
        element.velocity({
          translateX: "-66.666666%"
        }, {
          duration: 750,
          delay: 4000
        }, "easeOut");
        $('.multi-nav .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.multi-nav .1').addClass("active");
        self.i++;
        break;
      case 2:
        element.velocity({
          translateX: "0%"
        }, {
          duration: 750,
          delay: 4000
        }, "easeInQuart");
        $('.multi-nav .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.multi-nav .2').addClass("active");
        self.i = 0;
        break;
    }
  }, 5000);
}

Slider.prototype.stop = function() {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  console.log(timer);
}

var id = 0;
var name = "slider_";
$(".multi").each(function() {
  uniqueName = name + id;
  window[uniqueName] = new Slider($(this));
  id++;
});


$(".multi-nav a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Stopping the object running on this object.
  var id = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(" ").pop();
  uniqueName = name + id;
  window[uniqueName].stop();
});
```

Comment: don't think you realize that there are numerous timers...not just one. OP needs to clear the correct instance. A global will get overwritten each iteration

Comment: I was going to say, my only issue with that is that I'm running at minimum two timers, with potential for many more.

Comment: First, this shouldn't be needed. Second, it makes the code uglier. Third, how would it work with multiple Sliders?

Comment: Multiple sliders? Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `setInterval` at all. Using `setTimeout` negates in most cases a need to keep a handle. Let the function being called determine the need for a new timed call.

```
function MyTimedObject() {
  this.stop = false; // flag to stop timeout
  var timed = function() { // timed function
    if (this.stop) {
      this.stop = false; // clear the stop flag ready if needed again
      return;
    }

    //... code does its thing ...

    // schedule next time
    setTimeout(this.timedFunc, 5000);
  }

  this.timedFunc = timed.bind(this); // bind the timed function to this;
}

var obj = new MyTimedObject();
// to start the timed function
obj.timedFunc();

// to stop it
obj.stop = true; // yes the timeout is still active 
// but it will do nothing when it does execute

// to restart it
if (!obj.stop) { // make sure it has stopped;
  obj.timedFunc();
} else {
  obj.stop = false; // just let it continue
}
```

Though not suitable for all situations I find this approach easier to manage and is how the `requestAnimationFrame` is managed.